# Why does clearTimeout execute immediately?

Tags: javascript

Hie!

I'm doing a test task, creating "slow_guard" function that should consoles warning message if another function passed to slow_guard executes too long.

Here is my code ([codepen](https://codepen.io/g1un/pen/WzabwB?editors=0011)):

```
function slow_guard(timeout, fn) {
  var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Function lasts for more than ' + timeout/1000 + ' sec.!');
  }, timeout + 1);
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  fn();
  var end = new Date().getTime();
  var time = end - start;
  console.log('Execution time: ' + time);  
  clearTimeout(timer); 
  // if(time < timeout) { clearTimeout(timer); }
}

function longFunction() {
  for (i = 0; i < 7999000; ++i) {
  // do something
  }
}

slow_guard(1000, longFunction);
```

But it doesn't work. It seems like clearTimeout doesn't wait for loop end and executes immediately.
If I use additional check using Date it works fine (you can check it replacing the code `clearTimeout(timer)` with the lower commented one).
Why does this happen?! Explain, please!

Comment: because you call it.....

Comment: You just cant. Javascript is single threaded.

Comment: `setTimeout` is not a blocking process, it's asynchronous. So the code reaches `clearTimeout` and executes before the timeout is done.

Comment: Yes, in your code the call to `clearTimeout()` will happen before the timer fires. Timeouts do not interrupt code that's running synchronously like your "long" function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` will queue a function to run later, but if you're in the middle of executing another function, it won't be interrupted to resolve the queued function.

The JavaScript engine will finish running `slow_guard` (including the `clearTimeout` call) before it checks the queue to see if there are any timed functions waiting to go (which there won't be because you just cleared it).

Comment: so any queued function inside another one will wait for end of this another function?

Comment: Where the function was queued from is irrelevant. The queue won't be checked while another function is running.

Comment: Hm, so now even with commented check my slow_guard function doesn't work properly